# Right click open in a new tab does not work with window.open in angular 11

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have a problem of redirection on  tags my angular application (version 11).

When I left click on the link, the redirection is done correctly.

When I do a ctrl+left click it's ok too.

However when I right click and "open in a new tab" then this new tab does not redirect to the expected link but to the home page of my application.

```js
  redirectTo() {
      window.open("https://www.mylink.com");
    }
```

```html
         <a (click)="redirectTo()">My link</a>
```

Do you have a solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will add the target to your `window.open` function

```js
window.open("https://www.link.com", '_blank');
```

If you wanted to achieve this using HTML only

```html
<a href="www.link.com" target="_blank">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is achievable with plain HTML

```
<a href="https://www.mylink.com">My link</a>
```

Or even better to [create a directive for external url](https://adrianfaciu.dev/posts/angular-router-external-links/).